# Is there any way to have a fully portable Java EE 6 deployment?

Tags: jboss, java-ee-6

Is it possible to make a Java EE 6 application deployable on any Java EE 6 Container (like JBoss or GlassFish, etc) without using their modules / libraries?

If for example I want Hibernate or Weld then  add these in my Maven pom.

In other words, is there any "vanilla" container or can JBoss or GlassFish be made "vanilla"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m sorry... but to be honest I don´t understand your question.

Java EE applications are in most cases deployable an all containers - as long as they are not using packages or configurations which are specific to the chosen container.
Even if you add libraries in your POM and the applications are packaged as WAR or EAR this *should* work.

Weld is not needed because the API is part of Java EE 6. If you want to use JPA you also don´t need hibernate.

Comment: it's probably true in theory but we can suppose that some 3rd party library may work with a specific implementation ... ex aplugin which work with CXF only ...

Comment: Of course. But since there isn´t mentioned a specific deployment problem for a container I assume the question is meant in a more general way. Even hibernate and Weld should be no problem.

Comment: related question, can i use 2 implementation of jax-rs on the same container ? (on different war for sure ...)

Comment: If the container is JEE compliant it should be possible because the applications should use different classloaders. There are containers (older JBoss f.e.) which have bogus classloaders and have problems with that. Problematic are always different packages of libraries which are already preinstalled on the server.